# What is bhramcharya or 3rd percept?

Tags: sutras, dhammas

Is it only pertaining to "no adultery" for layman or as "no sex" for monk?

If such is the case, why in ganika sutta it was mentioned as "path middle to celibacy and adultery" for ganika(female dancers)?

Conclusion:: 3rd percept varies from person to person. It is different for one who has the capacity to "no sex", one having capacity to "no adultery", one who has the capacity to "no sensual pleasures", one who has no-capacity or livelihood depends on adultery-- so "middle to adultery and no-sex(celibacy)",.........

It's main purpose is to enforce people of various livelihoods, various traditions, various spiritual-levels, various situations(incidents) to realize the **cravings associated** with "`harmone-loss through privates, mental-exhaustance in sensual-pleasings, breaking-percepts, various-perceptions, sankharas, ignorance`".

Is above conclusion true? Yes/No then justify?

*(wholesomeness has essence and craving of never-dying.)*

Comment: I think this question is more about the Ganika Sutta and should be rewritten and reopened.

Comment: Hi, please study previous questions before opening new ones. Then, make an effort to formulate a unique question. Avoid providing your own answer. "Am I right or am I right?" types of questions are not encouraged.

Comment: Also may I recommend that you use only one user account. I know it's "identity" (and that it's possibly even funny to impersonate others) -- but I think it's useful though. I think that having a reputation -- posting content which is traceable to an author and theoretically even a real-world person -- can be helpful: that it can be an incentive which encourages you to behave as well as possible (a bit similar to the way in which "conceit" can be beneficial on the path).

Answer (score 3):

Abhramcharya means non-celibacy. **Avoiding bhramcharya** is not the 3rd precept within the Five Prevents. Avoiding abhramcharya is for monks or for strict followers of the Noble Path following Eight or Ten Precepts.

As for Ud 6.8, it does not appear to be about celibacy but about attachments arising in the mind due to celibacy. In Ud 6.8 (Ganika Sutta), there are lay people involved in immoral sex. Then the monks became morally outraged by this and criticized to the Buddha those lay people involved in immoral sex. Thus the Buddha remarked: both the immoral laypeople and the monks disturbing their minds via aversion to immorality are both on the wrong path.

Comment: Apparently it is the 3rd of the "8 precepts" -- although, as you said, not the 3rd of the "5 precepts" -- the "8 precepts" are [for example here](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.14).